# Waiting for a value to be true, requires thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written a small method. It basically calls to a service (not web service) to set a lock attribute. It does work, but I am interested in improving it. Should I really be running this in a new thread?

I have this running inside a `do..while` and I have no `thread.sleep` between calls.

I am using the stopwatch to record when its actually more than 20 seconds and I exit anyway as no lock was able to be set.

```
public bool ObtainLock(Uri lockUri)
{
    bool lockResult = false;

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    do
    {
        lockResult = myService.SetLockBit(lockUri);
    }
    while (!lockResult || sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 20000);

    sw.Stop();

    return lockResult;
}
```

It just seems to me it could be improved, and the threading worries me. A note, the myservice isn't a web service, its just another method on a class so I can use `Task<..>` here.

And the stopwatch I am using, is that an acceptable way of implementing a timeout?

Comment: You can use the c# Task library to solve this if you're using .NET 4, are you sure it's not available?

Comment: What is `SetLockBit`?  What's it doing?  Without knowing what it's supposed to do, there isn't much for us to say about the caller.

Comment: Its writing a line to a sequential file .. not ideal. but I have to work with it !

Comment: Maybe your question is "how to use asynchronous web and file I/O APIs?"

Comment: @Martin We need to know more than that.  If it's a properly implemented asynchronous operation it should have *some* means of exposing when it's "done", whether it be an event, a callback, a `Task`, or what have you.  If it has none, then ideally you'd be changing the method to add such a mechanism to it.  If none of that exists or is possible, then there really isn't anything to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would if this is your UI thread. Perhaps a `Timer` would be better? Perhaps you should use a `SpinLock`?

Answer (score 0):

If this can be improved or not depends on what's going on. Should you spawn a new thread for this? If you need the current thread for something else (e.g. UI updates) while you're waiting to `SetLockBit`, then yes. If you don't need the current thread to do anything, then this is fine.

The stopwatch is fine. However, if you know that locks are likely to be held for seconds at a time, you may want to wait a bit longer before calling `SetLockBit` again. If you know that they are released very quickly, but there's a lot of contention, then you may want to keep this.